# How to get a character from a serial Parsed http response?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, ethernet

I am a web developer and I am struggling with C code on Arduino. So this is What I have:

I have a backend written on PHP that returns a 0 or 1 depending of wether a pin should be high or low. I have an Arduino UNO with a W5100 Ethernet shield mounted, and I'm currently connecting correctly to my server, this is my Arduino code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
//IPAddress server(74,125,232,128);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
char server[] = "www.api-qa1.enerzoo.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /api/DeviceState/1 HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.api-qa1.enerzoo.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}
```

And this is the response it outputs:

```
connecting...
connected
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date: Fri, 17 Nov 2017 23:36:14 GMT
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImIzTDJzQk1BUm1qY1BuZ1BJXC83Mk5BPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IlwvNjlmXC9FZWxDSW9vbGNcL1JZUU5tbTFvOVVXVjcxV0hHaDRKUzVGVVZCSmFCM1BcLzlSR2x5MmN4cnZ1ZHRvZmlcLzNSUWMrZEFDMTQzR05ORTk5R3dBUGc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjM4ZjVhY2IxOWVmZTMzMGY2OGE1MTNmZWY0NzczNGVhNWJhZjVkYzlkYzY4ODg3ZGI0OWVhNDYwOTkwYjgxYTAifQ%3D%3D; expires=Sat, 18-Nov-2017 01:36:14 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; HttpOnly

1a
||0||
0


disconnecting.
```

I need to get that zero that is enclosed between the double pipes

> ||0||

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Don't web developer learn about "substring" function? I bet even PHP have something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it. I avoided using regex expressions and "complex" functions such as substring in order to save memory. I just detected two consecutive pipes and get the next character (in this case 0 or 1) using a counter. Since I need to continuously be checking the status of the device, I reset the counter to 0 once I get the current state.

```
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    if(c == '|' || counter == 2){
      counter++;
      if(counter == 3){
        counter = 0;
      }
      if(c == '1' || c == '0'){
        Serial.print(c);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send json format instead of pipes enclosed and parse the value. Else use regex expression to match ||0|| or ||1|| .